# Nightwatch integration with Maven

Tags: maven, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

is it possible to include running tests with Nightwatch as part of a Maven build for Java applications? Currently my app completes the build and deploy and then a separate script is fired to run the Nightwatch tests. It would be a big win to wrap the multiple steps up into a single one.

Comment: the maven exec plugin and its exec goal could be used to run the script or what the script actually invokes

Comment: This helps but there is still a manual step of copying the runner out of /bin if the tests are to be run as part of the Maven build.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to run npm commands from maven.